# JScroll Strange Text Wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I"m Using JScroll to create a small scrollable section within a larger page and for some reason the text is appearing strangely wrapped

kind of 
like 
this 
for  
no reas 
on

JS

```
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function()
            {
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
            });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
<link href="jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

.scroll-pane
            {

                height: 200px;
                overflow: auto;
            text-align: centre;

            }
```

HTML

```
<section>
<div id="news">
<div class="scroll-pane"><pmain> <ins>Leeds Lieder Day of Song</ins><br />
<br />
I have recently been selected as the Sheffield Univesrity Representative at the Leeds Lieder organised &quot;Day Of Song&quot;. I&quot;m really looking forward to this opportunity to collaborate and create so hopefully great new work! </pmain><br />
<br />
<pmain> <ins><i>Phobophobia</i> premiered by Sheffield University Symphony Orchestra!</ins><br />
<br />
My first orchestral work <i>Phobophobia</i> was premiered by Sheffield University Symphony Orchestra on the 14th of December 2014, it was a great concert also featuring student co nductor Dom Hartley who performed John Adam&#39;s <i> Chairman Dances </i> and student soloist Emma Dowson who played the Pakhmutova <i>Concerto for Trumpet and Orchestra</i> </pmain></div>
</div>
</section>
```

The full page is [here](http://www.alexgw.co.uk/testing.html) if you wanted to look at the whole source

Thank you in advance I'm quite a beginner but I've made it this far now stuck on my last bit!

Update it's working fine in firefox so maybe a chrome issue

Comment: Solved it CSS had to be above JavaScript as per the known issues on the JScroll page